# Get item from Object without errors

Tags: typescript, enums

There is this code:

```
enum Stages { 
  BOOT = 'boot', 
  LOAD = 'load' 
}

interface A { … }
interface C<T> { … }

interface List {
  readonly [Stages.BOOT]: C<A>;
  readonly [Stages.LOAD]: C<A>;
}

class Main {
  constructor(
    readonly list: List
  ){}

  getItem <T extends A>(key: Stages): C<T> | null {
    if (key in this.list) return this.list[key] as C<T>; //here is the error
                               //^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return null;
  }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 
 'Stages' can't be used to index type 'List'.
Property '[Stages.LOAD]' does not exist on type 'List'
```

But the item exists, logging the object show the correct behavior. What's the catch here?

Comment: nope… that's undefined…

Comment: Hmm, [I can't reproduce this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBAygLgQwObAM5QN4FgBQUoBCA8kQCpQC8UA5AEYD29c1ANLvgDJECCAIpTQA29BABNquAL64AliDjAATgDMEAY2BRumKNJxyFK9ZoDCAHlIA+HXoNLVGqBxmo4mdlEXAx9EIICeUADa8MhoAHTEZAC6AFxQ5tyWANweXj5+gSGIKKjhXHxxCWZJqTh6aoIIqOgAsghy7nhQar6uimBqcPSKABQe+OmivgFQgi5w8c6uHgCUNrgeKHAAkgoQFlDAAB4KIKLoSb0A1sD+8aG5s-HmVlAAPlDggoJN+PgyylAnZ1CNcAALFzhcaueZeOBgRQgKCA4GguBBU7+aJQarFKxld6eYCQ6FPMAvLG6KS4IA).  Can you verify that your example code constitutes a [mcve]?

Comment: can you provide implementation for your interfaces `A` and 'C<T>'